# How to clone an Object (NOT an SObject!) with apex?

Tags: apex

Assume there is a custom class foo:

```
class foo {
  // ... some member variables here
}
```

and an instance of it

```
foo fooInstance1 = new foo();
```

how to make an independent copy fooInstance2 and not only an reference like that:

```
foo fooInstance2 = fooInstance1;
```

**Update**

There is an additional challange, that I can't serialize the class, because some of the members are unserializable (like `DescribeFieldResult` or `Exception`)

Answer (score 13):

The other "practical" way to do this through JSON:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = (Foo)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(a), Foo.class);
```

That said, JSON is majorly expensive, so you're better off writing your own copy constructor (as mentioned by @DerekF), which would be used like this:

```
Foo a = new foo();
Foo b = new foo(a);
```

I would suggest you post an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) for this.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox, I was aware of that trick, but my issue with that are some unserializable members  like schema-stuff or exceptions in the class...

Comment: @UweHeim Yeah, unfortunately it's either manual or JSON. I only wish we had real copy constructors.

Comment: @sfdcfox the link you posted is not leading to the Idea and I couldn't find it. I would love to up vote it...

Comment: @Basti there isn't an Idea for this. Someone needs to make one...

Comment: Maybe we can just add some details to this existing idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp5IAAS

Answer (score 11):

I think it, rather unfortunately, comes down to you need to make your own copy method/constructor. I don't recall seeing anything on copying class instances in documentation, and the base `Object` class isn't documented. I think I recall attempting to use `Object.clone()`, but got a syntax error.

Something like

```
class Foo{
    public Foo clone(){
        Foo theClone = new Foo();
        theClone.bar = this.bar;
        return theClone;
    }
}
// Usage
Foo instance1 = new Foo();
instance1.bar = 'baz';
Foo instance2 = instance1.clone();
```

or if your class members have private setters

```
class Foo{
    public Foo(Foo instanceToCopy){
        this.bar = instanceToCopy.bar;
    }
}
// Usage, assuming no public setter for member bar, and an appropriate constructor
Foo instance1 = new Foo('baz');
Foo instance2 = new Foo(instance1);
```

Comment: are you sure that clone() will only return again a reference and not an independent clone?

Comment: @UweHeim I don't think I quite understand what you're asking here. If the class member that you're trying to copy is an object (like, say, `Account` or `Exception`), I believe that assignment is done by reference. If it's for a primitive (like `String`, `Blob`, `Integer`, etc...), I believe the assignment is done by value. I'll have to do more investigation after I get back from lunch.

Comment: @DerekF It's more complicated than that (as is Java itself), but from a practical standpoint, you're correct.

Comment: Adding more validation on what Derek mentioned. There is no object.clone() available in apex. Apex will return reference for non-primitive type variables. Please see this article : //Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html

Answer (score 3):

The clone() method does exist for all objects, but only SObject has the overload with 4 booleans, making it an entirely different method. That is why you are getting a syntax error. Similarly, you could make your own overload on a custom class Foo:

```
public class Foo {
    // primitive members
    public integer myInteger = 0;
    public string myString = 'Hello';
    // complex members - depth 1
    public map<string,string> stringMap = new map<string,string>{'a'=>'1'};
    public list<string> stringList = new list<string>{'a','b','c'};
    // complex members - depth 2
    public map<string,list<string>> stringListByString = new map<string,list<string>>{
        'number'=>new list<string>{'1','2','3'},
        'letter'=>new list<string>{'a','b','c'}
    };

    public Foo() {

    }
    
    public Foo clone(boolean deepClone){
        // primitive
        Foo ret = this.clone();
        
        // complex
        if (deepClone){
            // complex[1]
            ret.stringList = stringList.clone();
            ret.stringMap = stringMap.clone();
            // complex[2]
            ret.stringListByString = new map<string,list<string>>();
            for (string key : stringListByString.keySet()){
                ret.stringListByString.put(key, stringListByString.get(key).clone());
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Here is a demo that you can run in anonymous apex. Just initialize deepClone to true or false:

```
Boolean deepClone; // Set me to true/false
Foo f1 = new Foo();
Foo f2 = f1.clone(deepClone); // deep clone 
// modify members on the clone
f2.myInteger = 1;
f2.myString = 'Goodbye';
f2.stringList.add('d');
f2.stringListByString.put('letter',new list<string>{'d','e','f'});
// compare primitive members 
system.debug(f1.myInteger == f2.myInteger);
system.debug(f1.myString == f2.myString);
// compare complex members 
system.debug(f1.stringList == f2.stringList); 
system.debug(f1.stringListByString == f2.stringListByString);
```

The first two debugs will always return false because primitive members are assigned by value during cloning. The last two debugs are checking for equivalence on complex members.They will both return true when using shallow clone, or false when using deep clone.

When you shallow clone, both instances will share a reference to the complex member, such that modifying the member on one will modify it on both. As you can see our deep clone implementation makes it so that each instance is actually pointing to a different instance or reference in memory for the complex members (collections, class instances, etc).